# Where can I find a Rebol 3 micro web server?

Tags: webserver, embedded-linux, rebol, rebol3

There are plenty of nice little web-servers written in Rebol 2, but Rebol 3 has a different networking model, and I'm looking for a web-server that works with that.

I'm not looking for anything fancy. It's just to run on an embedded board to let me control Insteon appliances around my house using Rebol 3 -- which is just a lot easier and cleaner than other methods.

*Please don't reply with non-Rebol based web-servers. I'm not interested in using those.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple web server created by Andreas Bolka (@earl)

https://github.com/earl/rebol3/blob/master/scripts/shttpd.r

It is HTTP 1.0 and has no SSL or other fancy features, and amazingly it is only 64 lines of code hence is ideal for an embedded server.

Comment: Update from @earl -
I published a few updates to my minimalist "shttpd" HTTP server implementation for Rebol 3. Most notably, a workaround was added to properly send reponses >32'000 bytes (thanks to Bo and Boleslav).

The full list of changes:

    Add a few select MIME types
    Switch default MIME type to application/octet-stream
    Use last "."-separated path component as extension
    Trim indentation from the error template
    Send content-length header
    Manually send body data in 32'000 byte chunks

    https://github.com/earl/rebol3/blob/master/scripts/shttpd.r